# Images repositioned in an email

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to send a mail using JSP.
I am able to send the html file and the images are also displayed in the email but the alignment of the images in not proper. (i.e the images repositioned from their ideal place ).
I am trying to edit the css but no luck.

Thanks .

```
package mail;

 public class Emailer {

private static final String staticAbove = "<html><head>"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">"
        + "<title>Insert title here</title>"
        + "</head><body>"
        + "<div class=\"background\" style=\"background-color: #d6d6d6; width: 510px; height: 980px; margin-left: 725px;\">"
        + "<font color=\"#868384\" size=\"2\" style=\"margin-left: 100px;\"><br>"
        + "If you are unable to see images <u><a href = \"emailer.html\">click here for HTML version</a></u>"
        + "</font>"
        + "<div class=\"foreground\" style=\"z-index: 5;\">"
        + "<div style=\"position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;\">"
        +           + "</div></div>"
        + "<div class=\"whiteAboveGray\" style=\"background-color: white; margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px; height: 650px; margin-top: -54px;\">"
        + "<div class=\"content\">"
        + "<h1> <font color=\"388293\" size=\"4\" face=\"TImes New Roman\" style=\"margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 8px;\">Dear Customer ,</font>"
        + "</h1>"
        + "<hr class=\"hr\" style=\"background-color: silver;\">"
        + "<font color=\"928888\">"
        + "<p align=\"justify\" style=\"margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 8px;\">"
                    + "</p>"
        + "<p align=\"justify\" style=\"margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 8px;\">"


        + "<p align=\"justify\" style=\"margin-top: 8px; margin-right: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 8px;\">"
        + "</font>";
;

private static final String dynamicContent = "<div class=\"dyanamicContent\">"

        +
```

Above is the html code.
There are 3 strings.
I am using these strings here..

```
  package mail;

  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Properties;

   import javax.mail.Message;
   import javax.mail.MessagingException;
   import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
   import javax.mail.Session;
   import javax.mail.Transport;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

   import com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822;
```

public class MailUtility {

```
private static final String STATUS_ARCHIVE = "archive";

private CoverLetter coverLetter;
List<MailPropertiesInfo> successfullPropertiesList;

private static final String EMAIL_ID = "";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";

public void sendSuccessMail(List<MailPropertiesInfo> successfullPropertiesList, String sendToEmailId, String propertyId)
{
    Message message = initializeMailSetting(sendToEmailId);
    coverLetter = new CoverLetter();
    String messageForUSerHavingProperties = CoverLetter.getMessageforuserhavingproperties();
    StringBuilder content = getContent(successfullPropertiesList);

    try 
    {
        message.setSubject("");
        message.setContent(messageForUSerHavingProperties
                +"<b><u>Your Property ID is:  </b>"
                + propertyId+"</u>\n\n"+content,
                "text/html");

        Transport.send(message);
    //out.println("<b>Done</b>");
    } 
    catch(MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private StringBuilder getContent(
        List<MailPropertiesInfo> successfullPropertiesList) {

    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;

    for(MailPropertiesInfo mailProp : successfullPropertiesList)
    {
        content.append(mailProp.toString());
        content.append("\n\n");
        count++;
        if(count == 5) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }   

    return content;
}

public void sendNoPropertiesMail(String sendToEmailId, String propertyId) 
{

    Message message = initializeMailSetting(sendToEmailId);

    coverLetter = new CoverLetter();
    String messageForUserNotHavingProperties = CoverLetter.getMessageforusernothavingproperties();
    try 
    {
        message.setSubject("Property Suggestion From DoMyDeal");
        message.setContent(Emailer.getStaticabove()+Emailer.getDynamiccontent()+Emailer.getStaticbelow() 
                +"<b><u>Your Property ID is: </b>"
                +propertyId,
                "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
    } 
    catch(MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Message initializeMailSetting(String sendToEmailId) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session123 = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD);
            }
        });

    Message message = null ;

    try
    {
        message = new MimeMessage(session123);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("domydealportal@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse(sendToEmailId));              

    }
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return message;
}

public CoverLetter getCoverLetter() {
    return coverLetter;
}

public void setCoverLetter(CoverLetter coverLetter) {
    this.coverLetter = coverLetter;
}

public List<MailPropertiesInfo> getSuccessfullPropertiesList() {
    return successfullPropertiesList;
}

public void setSuccessfullPropertiesList(
        List<MailPropertiesInfo> successfullPropertiesList) {
    this.successfullPropertiesList = successfullPropertiesList;
}
```

}

Comment: Many e-mail client's like outlook express, and other's support very less css rules. you have to read the instruction, when developing emailer. here is a link, may be help you. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my tips are, don't use `div`s, only use tables for emails designs. Or use a pretested email template such as one from http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/